# Change default size of the <p> tag in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to change the default font size of the CKEditor `<p>` tag.

I have tried all given options in documentation but nothing is working.

```
config.format_p = { element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'normalPara' } };
config.format_p = { element: 'p', attributes: { 'style': 'font-size:20px' } };

config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '12px';

config.fontSize_style = {
    element:        'p',
    styles:         { 'font-size': '#(size)' },
    overrides:      [ { element: 'font', attributes: { 'size': '100px'} } ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the default style available in the `contents.css` file. You can use the [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) configuration option to point to your custom styles (to avoid overwriting changes introduced to the default `contents.css` file on upgrade).